# ocurl extract output from individual curl request in multi-request handle

Tags: curl, ocaml

I'm trying to start many HTTP requests simultaneously in a script. I'm using the ocurl library (which is a thin wrapper around libcurl) and trying to read information out of a curl multi handle.

The following example using a simple curl handle works great and dumps the response to stdout

```
module C = Curl ;;

let get_handle () =
    let () = C.global_init C.CURLINIT_GLOBALALL in
    let handle = new C.handle in
    let () = begin
        handle#set_url "google.com";
        handle#set_followlocation true;
    end in
    handle ;;

let main () =
    let obj = get_handle () in
    obj#perform ;;

main () ;;
```

I'm trying to do the same thing with a trivial multi-exec handle that only contains a single request to get a better understanding of the API. I'm trying to use the `set_writefunction` method (which is a thin wrapper around [CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION.html)) to write the output of an individual request to a module-scoped variable containing a string reference. The closure I'm using assigns the string to `message` and then returns the number of bytes written. I was expecting to see either the entire document I fetched in message, a trailing fragment of it (if curl internally calls my callback multiple times with chunks of the content), or an empty string (if curl uses an empty string to mark the end of the content and my callback is supposed to handle that case). Instead it prints `generic initial value`, which shows that the callback was never invoked. Why isn't  my callback being invoked?

```
module C = Curl ;;
module M = Curl.Multi ;;

let message = ref "generic initial value" ;;

let get_handle () =
    let () = C.global_init C.CURLINIT_GLOBALALL in
    let handle = new C.handle in
    let () = begin
        handle#set_url "google.com";
        handle#set_followlocation true;
        handle#set_writefunction (fun str -> (message := str; String.length (!message)));
    end in
    handle ;;

let batch () =
    let newhandle = get_handle () in
    let multi = M.create () in
    let () = M.add multi newhandle#handle in
    let _ = M.perform multi in
    Printf.printf "%s\n" (!message) ;;

let main () = batch () ;;

main () ;;
```